# jQuery Ajax maintain POST Html notation

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, notation

Is it possible to maintain the Php post notation using a Ajax Post. For example, if I do a standard post using a HTML form and var_export the $_POST data I can see the structure of any array data. I'd like to maintain this when using a Ajax Post, I've tried using jQuery serialise and serialiseArray but these don't maintain the same format.

Answer (score 0):

This should work like a charm:

```
$.post("test.php", $("#form").serialize(),
   function(data){
     alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I've tried this but because I have form data that stores values like tier[1][tiers][5][groupId] and tier[1][tiers][5][groupName] the data doesn't come through correctly, or it does but in a string form.